# Speed up copying values

Tags: excel, vba

This code takes 8 cells from a data entry form and copies those cells to the next empty row on another worksheet that is used as a database. It takes 15 seconds. It can speed up the code if it didn't copy to another sheet.

Is there a way to significantly speed up this code without merging the two sheets?

```
sub UpdateLogWorksheet1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim historyWks As Worksheet
Dim inputWks As Worksheet

Dim nextRow As Long
Dim oCol As Long

Dim myRng As Range
Dim myCopy As String
Dim myclear As String
Dim myCell As Range
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "sallygary"

myCopy = "e4,g26,g16,g12,g18,g20,g22,g24"
Set inputWks = Worksheets("Dept 1 Input")
Set historyWks = Worksheets("1_Data")

With historyWks
    nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End With

With inputWks
    Set myRng = .Range(myCopy)

End With

With historyWks
    With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
        .Value = Now()
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    End With
    .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
    oCol = 3
    For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
        historyWks.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
        oCol = oCol + 1
    Next myCell
End With

With inputWks
  On Error Resume Next
     End With
  On Error GoTo 0
ActiveSheet.Protect "sallygary"
Range("g12").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Posting a poor question, having it close-voted, deleting it, and posting almost the same identical question again with a different title rarely works. It's always better to actually **edit the question and improve it** instead. Work on doing that, please.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: The almost identical question that was posted by another 1-rep user, describing the identical problem in almost the same way, with almost the same exact code, that received several close and downvotes in a few minutes, was deleted by the poster, and then appeared here (with the same *Can anyone make this faster?* type question) about 2 minutes later.

Comment: how about turning calcs to manual?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: turning off auto Calc saved 5 seconds.  This is good.  I should've thought of that.  I do it all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't copy cell by cell. Copy Entire tables with one operation. For example to copy a 100×3 table

```
Sheet2.Range("A2").Resize(100,3).Value2 = Sheet1.Range("G2").Resize(100,3).Value2
```

Comment: Note this will not copy formulas. It will copy everything as values.